# PowerBI M: How to code in an exclusion to an IF statement

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm working to programmatically clean up a field in my dataset by using a Helper column that I will later filter on and remove the 'junk' records. The junk records are ID's, and the valid records are full names (in the format of "Tom Jones"). Almost all (there is a valid name value of "University") junk records do not contain a space. The pseudo code would read

```
Set Helper_IsName? = True
WHERE ValueField CONTAINS " " unless ValueField = "University"
ELSE False
```

Here is the M code excerpt that is getting me 95% of the way there:

```
Helper_IsName? = Text.Contains([OldValue]," ")
```

All results are good, except when the formula reads "University", it sets the value as `FALSE`, when I need it to equal `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add that condition with an `or`:

```
Helper_IsName? = Text.Contains([OldValue]," ") or [OldValue] = "University"
```